# MD5 generation overheat - Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, hash, md5

To make it short and firm:

I have an api which returns a md5 of a specific file. The files are about 50 - 100 MB large. Now my question is:

What would need less resources/is stylistic better:

1. Generating the md5 of the file for every GET
2. Generating the md5 the first time a GET asks for it and the watch the file with a `FileSystemWatcher` for changes and refresh the md5 if the file changes

It was told me that generating a md5 many times *could* produce a overheat.

Comment: Second is always better, less computations and faster.

Comment: Overheat due to computations?  Is that a real problem with modern computers?

Comment: @aaaabbbb We're talking about a small web application and not about a desktop application. Why wasting memory and processing power if there is a way to do it less enervating? Even if C# is quite performant you should keep an eye on performance when developing a application.

Comment: So your "overheating" isn't literal.

Comment: @aaaabbbb Well if somebody likes pressing F5 it could result in a massive overheat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second option will always be faster, how significantly depends on how often the file changes.

The most processing consuming operation you have is the MD5 hashing. If you have no choice but to hash the file with MD5, you should do all you can to reduce the number of times you do it. The ideal scenario would be to do it only once, which is exactly what would be doing with option 2.

That's supposing the file won't change, but definitely the chances to produce an overheat should be much lower than option 1, even if you change the file once every 5 minutes.

Comment: As the folder content would only change sporadically the second option would be definetly better. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to compute the MD5 beforehand, and save the MD5 along with the main file.

Computing it dynamically on the first call adds complexity and processing time that can easily be avoided.

Comment: It would be better, you're right. But as the files don't change often it would be more annoying for the webadmin to generate a md5 every time than just generating it once threw the app. If I had to make a real business solution I would do it like you said but as this is not used in a company I think a one time generation would be acceptable.